# How to input Key and Initialization Vector including special characters with openssl

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, openssl

I use this command to decrypt the file but it does not work because my Key and Initialization Vector including special characters

```
openssl  enc  -nosalt   -aes-256-cbc  -d   -in input.json -out   output.json  -base64    -K qwr{@^h`h&_`50/ra7!'dvmh3!uw<&=? -iv 6/#~V).A,lY&=t5b
```

Can someone show me where to improve?

Answer (score 0):

`openssl` wants those `-K` and `-iv` parameters in hex-encoded form, probably to avoid problems with command line parsing. From `man openssl`:

```
     -iv IV  The actual IV (initialisation vector) to use: this must be represented as a string comprised
             only of hex digits.  When only the key is specified using the -K option, the IV must
             explicitly be defined.  When a password is being specified using one of the other options,
             the IV is generated from this password.

     -K key  The actual key to use: this must be represented as a string comprised only of hex digits.  If
             only the key is specified, the IV must also be specified using the -iv option.  When both a
             key and a password are specified, the key given with the -K option will be used and the IV
             generated from the password will be taken.  It probably does not make much sense to specify
             both key and password.
```

How you do that, depends on what tools are available to you. If for instance you have the key stored in a file `key.raw` then you can use `xxd -g1 -c32 -l32 -p key.raw` to generate it, like this:

```
$ xxd -g1 -c32 -l32 -p key.raw
7177727b405e686068265f6035302f726137212764766d68332175773c263d3f
```

That encodes it one character at a time (`-g1`), and grabs 32 bytes in one line, avoiding accidentally encoding a newline character at the end.

You can embed that in the `openssl` command as `-K $(xxd -g1 -c32 -l32 -p key.raw)`. Similar for the IV parameter.